# Controller reloading on ui router state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having a problem I can't seem to figure out. When using ui-sref to change to a new state, the correct controller "does" load, but the current controller ALSO reloads. Twice in fact. (I set a break-point in the JavaScript and it hits that break-point twice).

Here is the relevant UI-router code:

```
.state('index',
{
    abstract: true,
    url: "/index",
    templateUrl: "app/shared/content.html"
})

.state('index.cardholder',
{
    url: '/cardholder',
    views: {
        'content': {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/cardholder/cardholder.html',
            controller: 'cardholderController'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                {
                    name: 'app',
                    files: ['app/views/cardholder/cardholderController.js']
                }
            ]);
        }
    },
    params: {
        loadParams: false
    }
})

.state('index.cardholderedit',
{
    url: '/cardholder/edit',
    views: {
        'content': {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/cardholder/edit/editCardholder.html',
            controller: 'editCardholderController'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                {
                    name: 'app',
                    files: ['app/views/cardholder/edit/editCardholderController.js']
                }
            ]);
        }
    },
    params: {
        id: null,
        template: null
    }
})
```

And here is the sref that calls the new state:

```
<a ui-sref="index.cardholderedit({ id:cardholder.empPersonDTO.personId, template:selectedTemplate})">
```

I did a search on cardholderController just to make sure I didn't have a naming issue somewhere - it all looks kosher.

Why is cardholderController reloading? How do I stop it?

Comment: show the view for the same

Comment: According to the state names, edit is not a child of cardholder but by matching urls maybe it is, I haven't played with ui-router in a while... You could try making the urls more unique and seeing if that's it